# How to deal with non-questioned values in multiple regression?

Tags: multiple-regression, missing-data

### Background

I have a sample of customers, that I asked whether they had experience with different communication channels of a company (e.g. twitter, online shop, physical store, etc.).

For each communication channel they experienced I asked them to evaluate how satsified they were with their experience.

Finally I asked them to rate their overall satisfication with the company.

### My task

Determine the influence of each communication channel on the overall satisfaction via multiple regression.

### My problem

To due the questionnaire design not every person rated every communication channel, as most people do not experience all channels.
However this creates missing data that I can not handle with simple listwise deletion as this would delete almost the complete sample.

### Solutions I tried

At the moment I can think of two ways to tackle this problem but I do not know a) which of these is better and b) how to do this completely:

**1.) Treating missing values not as missing but rather as a viable value "Not experienced"**. This seems logical to me, since it can be assumed that not experience a communication channel is somewhat due to choice and says something about the overall satisfaction. However I do not know how to code this properly. by adding the value "Not experienced" do I treat the original ordinal satisfaction variable a nominal variable or would it be okay to treat the non-response as a lower value then 1 - Not satisfied at all?

**2.) Imputing the missing values under the assumption that they are not MCAR.** This seems difficult to me because every respondent has multiple variables with missing values instead of just one, so I do not know how to impute so many variables at once (e.g. for most respondents I would need to impute 5-8 variables out of 10).

Thank you all very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem might be well-suited to hierarchical linear modelling, such that satisfaction is nested in channels. The way you describe your data, it might be organized in a "wide format:"

```
Participant  Satisfaction through Channel X  ...  Satisfaction through Channel j
1            1x                              ...  1j
2            2x                              ...  2j
...          ...                             ...  ...
i            ix                              ...  ij
```

The first step is to reformat your data into a "long format:"

```
Customer  Channel  Satisfaction
1         x        1x
.         .        .
.         .        .
.         .        .
1         j        1j
2         x        2x
.         .        .
.         .        .
.         .        .
2         j        2j
.         .        .
.         .        .
.         .        .
i         j        ij
```

In this format, missing data is less of a problem. With $overall$ as your outcome variable, $customer$ indexed as $i$, and $channel$ indexed as $j$, your mixed model for the hierarchical linear model would be:

$overall=\gamma_{00}+\gamma_{01}(channel_j)+\gamma_{10}(satisfaction_{ij})+\gamma_{11}(channel_j)(satisfaction_{ij})+e_{ij}+U_0+U_1$.

To determine the influence of each channel, you could compare the statistical significance of $\gamma$ parameters. Better yet, would be to add channels to your data in a stepwise manner to determine which channel reduces the variance of the $U_0$ and $U_1$ terms.

It might be tempting to just run the "long format" as a multiple linear regression, but you will have inflated type-I error rates because the nesting structure violates the assumption of independence.

For more information on this type of model, see Raudenbush & Bryk (2002).

Comment: Wow, thanks for the great advice. I will certainly try your way because it looks promising. Just a couple of follow-up questions to understand everything: 1) Multiple linear regression is out, even if I go about it stepwise or even use something similar to shapely regression, correct? 2) I use SPSS, can you refer the package or analysis name I would have to use for analysis?

Comment: You can use multiple regression, but if the ICC is meaningful, you'll violate the assumption of Independence. There's a lot of smack talk about stepwise regression in my field, but I'm aware that's different for others. I've never heard of Shapley regression, so I can't comment. If you use normal multiple regression and the ICC is small, then I'd recommend contrast coding. I'm an `R` user, so I can't comment much on SPSS, but I believe it's the `\MIXED` command.

Comment: wondering which R packages did you use for HLM?